# Отключение сортировки в django admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

На странице django admin мне нужно отключить сортировку вообще, чтобы пользователь не мог отсортировать по возрастанию или убыванию, я не совсем понимаю где я могу отключить подобное.
из всего что я нашел это сделать `ordering = []`, отключить в Meta модели ordering и переопределить метод get_ordering такую конструкцию:

```
def get_ordering(self, request):
    return []
```

Ничего из этого не помогло, подскажите что еще можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `admin.py`, в классе модели, для которой необходимо отключить сортировку, пропишите `sortable_by = ()`.

> Если вы хотите отключить сортировку для некоторых столбцов, задайте sortable_by в виде коллекции подмножеств list_display, которые вы хотите сделать сортируемыми. Пустая коллекция отключает сортировку для всех столбцов.

[Здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.sortable_by:%7E:text=ModelAdmin.sortable_by) вы найдёте больше информации.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли)